# Other method for iterating an enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Initially I had the following:

```
[Flags]
public enum QueryFlag
{
    None = 0x00,
    CustomerID = 0x01,
    SalesPerson = 0x02,
    OrderDate = 0x04
}
```

As check boxes are checked/unchecked, I would add/remove flags from:

```
QueryFlag qflag;
```

My idea - when the user clicks the Search button, I would iterate the actual flags set in `qflag` to modify a `.Where` clause in my LINQ to Sql. However, `Enum.GetValues(qflag.GetType())` returns all the values of the QueryFlag itself. Not helpful.

My solution:

```
class myForm : Form
{
    List<QueryFlag> qflag = new List<QueryFlag>();

    private void chkOrderDate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkOrderDate.Checked && !qflags.Contains(QueryFlag.OrderDate))
            qflags.Add(QueryFlag.OrderDate);
        else
            qflags.Remove(QueryFlag.OrderDate);
    }

    private void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (qflags.Count == 0)
        {
            rtfLog.AppendText("\nNo search criteria selected.");
            return;
        }

        foreach (QueryFlag flag in qflag)
        {
            rtfLog.AppendText(string.Format("\nSearching {0}", flag.ToString()));

            // add switch for flag value
        }
    }
}

public enum QueryFlag
{
    CustomerID,
    SalesPerson,
    OrderDate
}
```

I have 3 check boxes and this works without any issues to this point. But I am wondering if there is a better way to perform this iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you had it originally was correct; you just got messed up by the `Enum.GetValues` method. This method returns every defined value for a particular `enum` type, yes. So what you *do* with this is check each *defined* value against your *particular* `enum` value to see whether the defined value is set within your value.

That is, you *should* do this:

```
private void chkOrderDate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkOrderDate.Checked)
    {
        qFlag |= QueryFlag.OrderDate;
    }
    else
    {
        qFlag &= (~QueryFlag.OrderDate);
    }
}
```

...and likewise for your other CheckBoxes. Then when you want to enumerate what flags you have set:

```
static IEnumerable<QueryFlag> GetFlags(QueryFlag flags)
{
    foreach (QueryFlag flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(QueryFlag)))
    {
        // Presumably you don't want to include None.
        if (flag == QueryFlag.None)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if ((flags & flag) == flag)
        {
            yield return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, you could even abstract the above into a handy extension method for all `enum` types:

```
public static class FlagsHelper
{
    // This is not exactly perfect, as it allows you to call GetFlags on any
    // struct type, which will throw an exception at runtime if the type isn't
    // an enum.
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetFlags<TEnum>(this TEnum flags)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        // Unfortunately this boxing/unboxing is the easiest way
        // to do this due to C#'s lack of a where T : enum constraint
        // (there are ways around this, but they involve some
        // frustrating code).
        int flagsValue = (int)(object)flags;

        foreach (int flag in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
        {
            if ((flagsValue & flag) == flag)
            {
                // Once again: an unfortunate boxing/unboxing
                // due to the lack of a where T : enum constraint.
                yield return (TEnum)(object)flag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So your `cmdSearch_Click` handler could look like this:

```
private void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (qFlag == QueryFlags.None)
    {
        rtfLog.AppendText("\nNo search criteria selected.");
        return;
    }

    foreach (QueryFlag flag in qFlag.GetFlags())
    {
        rtfLog.AppendText(string.Format("\nSearching {0}", flag.ToString()));

        // add switch for flag value
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not allow you to unset bits.  The original properly tested the `Checked` property.

Comment: @Ben: Good catch; that was just a dumb oversight on my part. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Dan: thanks...don't know why I didn't think about comparing the flags set in `qflag` to the enumeration values. Makes sense. I don't think I want to go the extension method route - the boxing/unboxing is extremely unappealing for this project; however, I will keep it in mind should the need arise.

Comment: @Dan - To remove an item of the `enum`, you are using `qFlag &= (~QueryFlag.OrderDate);` while I'm using `flags=flags ^ QueryFlag.OrderDate;`. Any difference? Or I made a mistake? Thanks.

Comment: @Danny: No, you didn't make a mistake! Either way works, actually: `qFlag &= (~QueryFlag.Order)` (which is less idiomatic, I believe) essentially ANDs each bit in `qFlag` with 1 (*except for* the `QueryFlag.Order` bit) whereas `qFlag ^= QueryFlag.Order` XORs each bit with 0 (except for that bit). As you can see, the result is the same either way.

Comment: @Dan Tao - Yes I made! See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748516/how-can-i-know-items-is-in-the-enum) I asked just now.

Comment: XOR only turns the bit off if it was previously on, while AND NOT always turns it off.

Comment: @Danny, @Ben: You're right; setting `flags ^= QueryFlag.OrderDate` actually *toggles* the `OrderDate` bit rather than turns it indiscriminately off. I suppose when you read others' suggestions to use this method, they are generally assuming that you already know for a fact the bit is set. So `flags &= ~QueryFlag.OrderDate` is more accurately the same as `if ((flags & QueryFlag.OrderDate) == QueryFlag.OrderDate) { flags ^= QueryFlag.OrderDate; }`

Answer (score 0):

The short, cheesy, and inefficient way:

```
qflag.ToString().Split('|')
```

Comment: Yeah, but then he's got to parse the strings back to enums. But you're right: even this will work.

Comment: Parsing the strings back to enums might not be forward progress, at this point I'd probably reach for a `Dictionary<string, CheckBox>`.  With a call to `string.Trim()` thrown in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but really at that point haven't you arrived at a solution about as bloated as what the OP already had (with a `List<QueryFlag>`)? I think he really was about 90% of the way there already with his `[Flags]`-based approach; he just got thrown off when it came time to *enumerate* a set of flags.

Comment: Bloated in terms of runtime inefficiency, sure.  But in terms of code reuse, it's actually pretty good.  Especially if `ControlCollection::Find` is used, then the designer can be used to wire up the list.

Comment: Hhmmm...interesting. @Ben is correct; I got thrown off expecting specific results. When I got unexpected results, I resorted to another solution. Frankly, if it came down to choosing my implementation or the `.Split('|')`, I would choose mine. :)