# How can I know items is in the enum?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums, extension-methods

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746291/other-method-for-iterating-an-enum), I use xor operator between `enum` with `[Flags]` attribute as following:

```
[Flags]
enum QueryFlag
{
  None = 0x1,
  ByCustomer = 0x2,
  ByProduct = 0x4,
  ByDate = 0x8
}
QueryFlag flags = QueryFlag.ByCustomer | QueryFlag.ByProduct;
```

To add an QueryFlag, of course we should use `|` operator.

```
flags |= QueryFlag.ByDate;
```

To remove one, I have a different way with [Dan Tao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746291/other-method-for-iterating-an-enum/3746604#3746604). I'm using:

```
flags ^= QueryFlag.ByProduct;
```

while he is using:

```
flags &= ~QueryFlag.ByProduct;
```

Obviously his answer is correct and easy to understand. I thought I made a mistake. But after a deep thought I got:

```
a,b         a^b         a&(~b)
0,0          0           0
0,1          1           0   //the difference
1,0          1           1
1,1          0           0
```

And now I knew my mistake. `^` is wrong when you try to remove one item which doesn't exist.

```
QueryFlag q = QueryFlag.ByCustomer | QueryFlag.ByDate;
//try to remove QueryFlag.ByProduct which doesn't exist in q
q ^ QueryFlag.ByProduct    //equals to add ByProduct to q, wrong!
q & (~QueryFlag.ByProduct) // q isn't changed, remain the original value. correct!
```

But here I got another question: how can I know if `q` contains one item? Base on Dan Tao's answer I wrote an extension:

```
public static bool Contains(this QueryFlag flags, QueryFlag flag)
{
   return (flags & (~flag)) != flags;
}
```

That is, if flags is not changed after removing flag from flags, we know flag is not in flags! It seems correct when:

```
(QueryFlag.ByProduct | QueryFlag.ByDate).Contains(QueryFlag.None)   //false
(QueryFlag.ByProduct | QueryFlag.ByDate).Contains(QueryFlag.ByDate)  //true
```

But in fact:

```
(QueryFlag.ByProduct | QueryFlag.ByDate).Contains(QueryFlag.ByDate | QueryFlag.ByCustomer) //true, but I suppose it's false
```

I know the reason why it's false, how can I improve it? It's the first question.
The second: I want to make the `.Contains` generic to more `enum` with `[Flags]` attribute.

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this T flags, T flag) where T : Enum//with [Flags]
{
    return (flags & (~flag)) != flags;
}
```

Probably it's impossible to constrain T with attribute marked. But even I remove this constraint I get a compile error which says `operator ~ can't be applied to type T`. Why and how to resolve?

Comment: Do you want .Contains(QueryFlag.ByDate | QueryFlag.ByCustomer) to return true if one of the flags is set, or only both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error lies in this method:

```
public static bool Contains(this QueryFlag flags, QueryFlag flag)
{
   return (flags & (~flag)) != flags;
}
```

This returns true whenever `flags` has *any* (i.e. *at least one*) of the flags contained in `flag`, but I think you want *all*.

It should read:

```
public static bool Contains(this QueryFlag flags, QueryFlag flag)
{
   return (flags & flag) == flag;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use `Enum.HasFlag()` which does exactly this. For example:

```
QueryFlag qf = ...;
if (qf.HasFlag(QueryFlag.ByCustomer))
    // ...
```

Comment: Oh! I don't know the `HasFlag` Method! That's exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A better way may be this:

```
return (flags & mask) == mask;
```

This will return true if all the flags set in `mask` are set in `flags`.

```
return (flags & mask) != 0;
```

This will return true is any of the flags set in `mask` are set in `flags`.

As for the generic method, you could try constraining the type to `struct`.  This constrains `T` to being a value type.

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this T flags, T mask) where T : struct
{
    return (flags & mask) == mask;
}
```

Comment: Now I understand your 2 answers to my first question. Thanks very much. However for the 2nd question, writing the constraint `where T:int` is incorrect, because `int` can't be a constraint of `where`.

Comment: True.  I'm still getting my head around type constraints.  It appears that you can specify struct as a constraint, which constrains T to being a value type.  See edited answer.

Comment: Answer is still wrong. You can’t use `&` or `==` on the `T` type. May I humbly recommend that you try to compile your code before you post it?