# Using Linq to find instances that contain a set of objects

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a set of bags.  Each bag contains a set of marbles.  I would like to select the bags which contain a specific combination of marbles.  What is the most efficient way to do this in linq?

In code:

```
public enum Marble { Red, Green, Blue}

public class Bag {
    public string Name;
    public List<Marble> contents;
}
var marbles = new[] { Marble.Red, Marble.Green };
 var bags = new [] 
            {new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
             new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
             new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}}
            };

//Output contains only bag Bar
var output = bags.Where(bag => bag.contents.All(x => marbles.Contains(x)) && 
                               marbles.All(x => bag.contents.Contains(x)));
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the set substraction operator is the one  that does it the way it should have been done in a much cleaner way. I have given both the method call and linq expression way of doing it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project
{
    public enum Marble { Red, Green, Blue}

    public class Bag {
        public string Name;
        public List<Marble> contents;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var marbles = new[] { Marble.Red, Marble.Green };
            var bags = new[] 
            {
                new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
                new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
                new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}},
                new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
                new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
                new Bag {Name = "Fiz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green}},
                new Bag {Name = "REDS", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Red}},
                new Bag {Name = "Biz", contents = new List<Marble> { Marble.Red } }, 
                new Bag {Name = "Griz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}},
                new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}}
            };

            // the method call version with set substraction operator
            var query_v2 = bags.Where(bag => bag.contents.Except(marbles).Count() == 0 &&
                                             marbles.Except(bag.contents).Count() == 0                                            
                                     );

            // print out the results 
            Console.WriteLine("query_v2...");
            foreach (var bag in query_v2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bag.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Follwowing is a LINQ Expression version
            var linqversion = from bag in bags
                              let diff1 = bag.contents.Except(marbles).Count()
                              let diff2 = marbles.Except(bag.contents).Count()
                              where diff1 == 0 && diff2 == 0 // perfect match ?
                              select bag;

            Console.WriteLine("Linq expression version output...");
            foreach (var bag in linqversion)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bag.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a great solution already, it appears.

Try with many varied + repeated bags! Your solution is readable enough, and covers the desired business logic.

```
 var bags = new[] 
        {new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
         new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
         new Bag {Name = "Fiz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green}},
         new Bag {Name = "REDS", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Red}},
         new Bag {Name = "Biz", contents = new List<Marble> { Marble.Red } }, 
         new Bag {Name = "Griz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}},
         new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}}
        };
```

<strike>Not sure why you need the second condition in your `Where()`.</strike>

This results in the single matching item, Bar.

```
 var output2 = bags.Where(b => b.contents.All(x => marbles.Contains(x))
                            && b.contents.Count == marbles.Count());
```

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while.  As for why the second where is required, here's a counter example.  `new Bag { Name = "Biz", contents = new List<Marble> { Marble.Red } }`.  As far as I can tell, he's looking for set equivalence.

Comment: @Jeff indeed. My solution failed the count as well, with 2 reds. :O

Answer (score 0):

<s>Here's an alternative solution.  Unsure about the performance though.</s>

```
var output = bags.Where(bag => !bag.contents.Except(marbles).Any());
```

Not quite right.

You may want to consider changing the collection type from `List<Marble>` to something like `HashSet<Marble>`.  This will allow you to do this:

```
var output = bags.Where(bag => bag.contents.SetEqual(marbles));
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with campbell's answer. Another suggestion is "why not use `[Flags]` attribute instead of `List<MyEnum>`"? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748516/how-can-i-know-items-is-in-the-enum) may give you some ideas on `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many bags and you want the greatest performance, you might look at using [PLinq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions):

```
public enum Marble { Red, Green, Blue }

public struct Bag
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Marble> contents;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var marbles = new[] { Marble.Red, Marble.Green };
        var bags = new [] 
        {new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
         new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
         new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}}
        };

        //Output contains only bag Bar
        var output = bags.AsParallel<Bag>().Where(bag => bag.contents.All(x => marbles.Contains(x)) &&
                                       marbles.All(x => bag.contents.Contains(x)));

        output.ForAll<Bag>(bag => Console.WriteLine(bag.Name));  // "Bar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the set substraction operator is the one  that does it the way it should have been done in a much cleaner way. I have given both the method call and linq expression way of doing it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;


    namespace Project
    {
            public enum Marble { Red, Green, Blue}

            public class Bag {
                public string Name;
                public List<Marble> contents;
            }




    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {

            var marbles = new[] { Marble.Red, Marble.Green };
            var bags = new[] 
                    {new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Foo", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Blue}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Bar", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Red}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Fiz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green}},
                     new Bag {Name = "REDS", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Red}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Biz", contents = new List<Marble> { Marble.Red } }, 
                     new Bag {Name = "Griz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Green, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}},
                     new Bag {Name = "Baz", contents = new List<Marble> {Marble.Red, Marble.Green, Marble.Blue}}
                    };





          // the method call version with set substraction   operator

           var  query_v2      = bags.Where(bag => bag.contents.Except(marbles).Count() == 0 &&
                                           marbles.Except(bag.contents).Count() == 0                                            
                                    );



               // print out the results 

               Console.WriteLine("query_v2...");

               foreach (var bag in query_v2)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(bag.Name);
               }



           Console.WriteLine();








           // Follwowing is a LINQ Expression version
           //
           var linqversion = from bag in bags
                             let diff1 = bag.contents.Except(marbles).Count()
                             let diff2 = marbles.Except(bag.contents).Count()
                             where diff1 == 0 && diff2 == 0 // perfect match ?
                             select bag;


           Console.WriteLine("Linq expression version output...");

            foreach (var bag in linqversion)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bag.Name);
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }









    }

}
```